# Remove edge styles on polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, color, fill

I have multiple polygons aligned next to each other. They are colorfilled with "Graduated" style. I have changed "Stroke style" to "No Pen".
How can I get the hairline between the polygons to disappear, so it is only the color fill one see?

[image]

Comment: You could change the border colour to the fill colour.

Comment: @Erik, the colors will change, depending on the color ramp and classes in my graduated fill. How can I lock the edge-color to the fill-color?

Comment: @JGH, where should I make these changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to have a small border and set that border to the same color as the polygons.

This can be done automatically by setting the border color to @symbol_color.

So graduated symbology, click on the Symbol at the top without highlighting any of the individual classes, this means that all of them will be edited:

[image]

Then we set a data defined override for the stroke color:

[image]

Which is just set to @symbol_color, which will use the same color as the main color:

[image]

Comment: It does. When you are editing from that top symbol button with none of the classes selected it applies the same edits to all of the classes. So it calculates @symbol_color for each class. I'm on 3.4 as well. This has been the behavior since probably 1.8.

Comment: Thanks for double-checking.. you are right, it works as you describe... I'm not sure why it failed on me yesterday